# Animate html list with smooth animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I want to animate html list from left to right and vice versa with fixed length. But when i click on right button it is working but it is replacing the list elements (no animation takes place).I want to show smooth animation which shows li elements moving left to right or right to left.

I tried

```
$elements.hide();
$elements.slice(counter, counter + showNum).show("fast");
```

But it still looks like replacing the li's.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sLJQ/5/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way for you would be to assign `position:relative` to your div `itemsListBox` and `position:absolute` to your list `ul`. Then using jQuery animate, you could animate it to left or right as required.

See your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/AtweK/1/**

And another variation: **http://jsfiddle.net/AtweK/2/**

*Relevant css*:

```
#itemsListBox {
    position: relative;
    height: 120px; width: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#itemsListBox ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 200%;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

*The code to animate*:

```
$('#leftArrow').on("click", function() {
    $('#slider').animate({left: "-=50"}, 500);
});

$('#rightArrow').on("click", function() {
    $('#slider').animate({left: "+=50"}, 500);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks , and what if i want to make it circular ?

Comment: @Nishant: this might give you an idea: http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/04/25/circular-image-slide-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to move elements with sliding effect. It is called carousel effect, there are many jQuery plugins to accomplish it, for example jCaraousel lite: http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

You can search on internet for similar other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

this will give little animation.

```
$elements.fadeOut();
$elements.slice(counter, counter + showNum).fadeIn("fast");
```

Comment: Please post some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Set css to position:relative in "itemsListBox ul li"

Then in jquery edit

```
$("#rightArrow").click(function(){
 $( "#itemsListBox ul li" ).animate({
    left: "+=50px",
  },5000);
});
$("#leftArrow").click(function(){
 $( "#itemsListBox ul li" ).animate({
    right: "+=50px",
  },5000);
});
```

Set the time duration as your requirement